# Classifiers for "1R","Naïve Bayes", "ID3" algorithms?

Tags: classification

Can anyone tell me if there are any Classifiers for "1R","Naïve Bayes", "ID3" algorithms (web application or desktop application)?

Thanks.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a 'classifier' in this context? Do you mean a specification, a document that describes the standard form of these algorithms?

Answer (score 2):

You can find implementations of these classifiers in the  [Weka toolkit](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) which you can either use directly on your data set using their GUI or call these algorithms from your own code.